How to start sidekiq/bundler via systemd service on rvm
so I have a systemd service to run my rails application, which works great.
[Service]
Type=exec
User=my-user
Group=my-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/my-user/my-app
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc "bin/rails server"

However, I started to use sidekiq and I am failing to get sidekiq to run.
Normally I can run it via bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml, but the issue is that my ruby version and binaries only get loaded when logging in normally.
I can't figure out how to do that. My current service looks like this:
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc "bin/rails server & /home/my-user/.rvm/bin/rvm in /home/my-user/my-app do bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml"


After some more testing and trying, I still am not able to get sidekiq to read from my config file, but using direct config flags does the job as well:
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bin/rails server & [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"; bundle exec sidekiq -q default,3 -q low_priority'


Do not start services with bash. Bash will trap signals and your service will not shutdown correctly. Start the service directly.
